# Storing 200 million variable length strings causes fragmentation/table bloat

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

I am attempting to store over 200 million key value pairs.  The value for over 50% of the keys will change over the course of the week, and about 5% of the rows will be permanently removed.  Using traditional SQL solutions, this has proven to cause a large amount of fragmentation, causing table bloat (4x the original table size), and some performance issues.  It takes considerable down time to resolve this fragmentation in SQL.  We have used both reindexing and reorganizing techniques, but both have failed to keep up with the fragmentation.  In addition I need to replicate this data to 2 other systems, which has also proven to be quite problematic.

The Table design is simple:

key NVARCHAR(50)

value VARCHAR(MAX)

We are considering using other technologies like MongoDB, but fear we will run into similar fragmentation issues.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we can come at this problem in a different way that might limit the fragmentation?

Comment: Key value tables like this are a disaster waiting to happen, suggest you reconsider your design. PLease read:

http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: What SQL server are you using? How large are the strings you are storing? Are you experiencing excessive page splits?

Comment: We are using SQL 2005.  The strings are commonly less than 1KB in size, but could be as large as 3KB.  The strings commonly change length when updating a given key's value.

Comment: @HLGEM: That is great article, but what makes you think this applies here? There are valid use-cases for key-value stores, and a system like MongoDB might be able to handle them better than a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for MongoDb.

MongoDb also supports [capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) (which you may be able to use). You can have object in your DB which in a sense scroll out of view when you no longer need them. Which could lessen your administration of the database if things are changing weekly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a way to create a versioning and partitioning mechanism even in MSSQL:

**Versioning**:
If a value is changed, the old value is marked as `is_active=False` and the new value is inserted. Then, you bulk delete values every week, which will cause less fragmentation overall. You can use a view to filter only the `is_actvie=True` values.

**Partitioning**:
I'm not sure what the best partitioning scheme would be best here. Since some values have a long lifespan, I think partitioning by time will not do the trick. Perhaps partitioning by key is better. This way, at least, you can try to defragment each partition separately, and the degradation is better contained.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is a good choice as it is easy to setup and administer, would give you easy horizontal scaling (excellent sharding support) and easy replication (via replica sets). The performance is excellent as long as the indexes fit in memory. However, MongoDb is also prone to fragmentation. The fragmentation can theoretically be managed since v2.0 by using the "compact" command. To compact the database without any down time you'd have to be using replication since the process would be:

- For each replica set (shard)

  - compact slaves
  - step down master
  - compact master
  - (optionally) resume original master

Here is a sample script: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-snippets/blob/master/js/compact-example.js